# Can handlebars walk up while iterating through lower level items?

Tags: handlebars.js

With the latest stable version of Handlebar, I'm trying to display the site name while iterating through each children.  The output of the code below is:

```
5
Stackoverflow
One -
Two -
```

Can handlebars retrieve the site name by walking up while rendering the children?

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="handlebars.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var source = $('#entry-template').html();
        var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
        var context = {
          site: {
            age: 5,
            name: 'Stackoverflow',
            children: [
              {
                name: 'One'
              },
              {
                name: 'Two'
              }
            ]
          }
        };
        $('div#output').html(template(context));
    });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="output"></div>
    <script id="entry-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
      <div>{{site.age}}</div>
      <div>{{site.name}}</div>
      {{#each site.children}}
      <div>{{name}} - {{site.name}}</div>
      {{/each}}
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try doing `{{../site.name}}` in your loop. The `../` Handlebars syntax allows access of the parent scope.